# Is it possible to reference a cell in Numbers using two column headers?

Tags: numbers, iwork

I am aware that I can reference cells using the name of row/column headers.

It looks something like this: `Sheet Name::Table Name::Column Name Row Name`.

However, I'm trying to reference something with *two* column headers.

I'm hoping that I can reference something like `Jan 2017::Balance:Salary` (pictured below).

[image: Screenshot of multiple headers.]

Is something like this even possible?